# Please check MySQL query

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to fetch data using MySQLi Query.
Please check my SQL Query, i'm getting error on the If condition.
i add error which is beside

> if condition

when it is getting displayed into console

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    include("../include/connection_string.php");


    $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT pages, main_id FROM dhms_index_table where main_id='"+$id+"'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)){ // Showing error here " Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result"
        $data = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            $data[] = array(
                'pages' => $row['pages'],
                'main_ID' => $row['main_id']
            );
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    ?>
```

connections_string.php

```
$server = 'localhost'; 
$username ="root"; 
$passwd =''; 
$Dbase = 'og_dhms'; 
$db = @mysqli_connect($server,$username,$passwd) 
        or die("Could not connect database"); 
@mysqli_select_db($db, $Dbase) 
        or die("Could not select database");
```

Comment: add `echo mysqli_error();` before if

Comment: I would guess the query has failed or the connection was not correctly made. Show us `connection_string.php`

Comment: Also look at your php error log and show us the full error message

Comment: $server = 'localhost';

$username ="root";

$passwd ='';

$Dbase = 'og_dhms';

$db = @mysqli_connect($server,$username,$passwd) or die("Could not connect database");
  @mysqli_select_db($db, $Dbase) or die("Could not select database");

Comment: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\DHMS\include\detailViewBg.php on line 17

Comment: Well that proves the **query has failed**. Show the `connection_string.php` code

Comment: $server = 'localhost';

$username ="root";

$passwd ='';

$Dbase = 'og_dhms';

$db = @mysqli_connect($server,$username,$passwd) or die("Could not connect database");
  @mysqli_select_db($db, $Dbase) or die("Could not select database");

Comment: Remove the `@` signs from the `connection_string.php` run the code again! Then look at the error log again. **You will probably see some errors**

Comment: Then look at the manual for [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: You are using + signs. That's why. Use dots

Comment: okay let me do those changes

Comment: Oh blimey: Totally missed that one. Thanks @Fred-ii-

Comment: @FlashThunder the syntax is `mysqli_error($link)` . Without the link it will return its own error of aving no connection specified!

Comment: @RiggsFolly What simple characters will do to someone's day, *eh?* ;-)

Comment: @Harshad Didn't I notice you accept my answer then unaccept? Pretty sure I wasn't hallucinating *lol*

Comment: @Martin not really... if there is only one database connection, it will refer to that one... no need to override default.

Comment: @FlashThunder sorry but that's incorrect,for procedural error logging the `mysqli_error()` function *requires* the link identifier.

Comment: @fred-ii : RIght answer was given posted by @ RiggsFolly. and fred-ii you were washing your hand in between thats why i have not accepted your answer

Comment: Harshad Well then, you should ask @RiggsFolly to put one in then. Oh and I just saw a new answer pop up now. *"washing my hands"*? I gave you the right syntax.

Comment: @Fred-ii- dirty hands are the cause of 16% of all programming errors, and 43% of all programming typos.

Comment: buddy i accepted your answer no issues for my side, at the end of the day
Stack overflow has resolve my issues :)

Comment: Harshad I don't have a problem with @RiggsFolly putting in an answer and for you to accept his if you feel that he did solve it for you. What's right is right ;-)

Comment: Yes @RiggsFolly solve my problem

Comment: @Martin yes, you're right.

Comment: @Harshad I think Fred-ii- deserves the points as he spotted the real issue

Comment: yes @Fred-ii- i apologies for my harsh statement. :)

Comment: @Harshad Don't worry about it. I didn't see anything harsh about it ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
main_id='"+$id+"'
```

is using `+` signs rather than dots to concatenate. That is the JS/C method to do that. Maybe you are from that type of background and thought you could use it in PHP; *you can't*.

so...

```
main_id='".$id."'
```

Also make sure you have a value for `$id = $_GET['id'];`.

Error reporting will tell you if it is or not.

If the GET array is an integer (which I am pretty sure it stands to be), you'd be best to use `(int)` for it.

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

and checking if it's set / not empty.

I.e.:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){

    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

}
```

or

```
if(!empty($_GET['id'])){

    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

}
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly *Cheers* then, would be fitting ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was most likely caused by a query syntax error here:

```
main_id='"+$id+"'
```

Changing that to this, should solve the issue:

```
main_id='".$id."'
```

But you should not use pure unfiltered user input in your sql statements.
I would do something like this:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
include("../include/connection_string.php");

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT pages, main_id FROM dhms_index_table WHERE main_id = ?")) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $pages, $main_id);
        $data = array();
        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            $data[] = array(
                'pages' => $pages,
                'main_ID' => $main_id
            );
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
?>
```

Always make sure to use prepared statements when you are including user input on statements to avoid SQL Injection.

Read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

I hope it helped.